# unable to change value of integer after looping, C++

Tags: c++, loops

At the start of my program I declare the variables `i` and `j`.

```
int i, j;
```

In the course of execution, I use the variable names `i` and `j` as a oop index variables too. I realize this is probably not the best choice in  terms of clarity, but as this is a toy project I thought it wouldn't matter.

The problem is, after the following loop that prints the contents of an array to a txt file, `i == N == 29`:

```
ofstream a_file("2d_array.txt");
for (int i = 0; i<N; ++i) {
  for (int j = 0; j<N; ++j)
    a_file << m[i][j] << ' ';
    a_file << endl;
}
```

When I try to use `i` again later in the program:

```
for (int num_slices_processed = h + 1; num_slices_processed < N;
         num_slices_processed++){
  i = 0;
  j = num_slices_processed;
  ...
```

`i` remains set to 29, even after the line that should set it to 0. `j` is set correctly though. What is happening here?

---

Here is all the code up to the problem section:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;
int smallest(int x, int y, int z);
bool basesMatch(char b1, char b2);

int main() {

    const int N = 29;
    int h, l, mm;
    int i, j;
    l = 10;
    mm = 2;
    h = 5;

    int m[N][N];

    //initialize m
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++){
        for (int j = i; j < N; j++) {
            if (j-i <= h)
                m[i][j] = 0;
        }
    }

    ofstream a_file("2d_array.txt");

    for (int i = 0; i<N; ++i) {
        for (int j = 0; j<N; ++j)
            a_file << m[i][j] << ' ';
        a_file << endl;
    }

    for (int num_slices_processed = h + 1; num_slices_processed < N; num_slices_processed++){
        //while j is in bounds, ie j < N. This fills in one diagonal slice of m from L->R top -> bottom.
        i = 0; //************ i is not being set here
        j = num_slices_processed;
        while (j < N) {
            if (basesMatch(seq[i], seq[j])) {
                t = m[i + 1][j - 1];
                m[i][j] = m[i + 1][j - 1];
            }
            else  {//bases don't match
                m[i][j] = smallest(m[i + 1][j] + 1, m[i][j - 1] + 1, m[i + 1][j - 1] + 1);
            }
            i++;
            j++;
        }
    }
```

Comment: If you declare `i` at the start of the function, why declare it again in the `for` loop?

Comment: "... *after the following loop that prints the contents of an array to a txt file, i == N == 29*" Not true. After the loop, `i` goes out of scope and no longer exists.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz there are two variables `i`.

Comment: @Adam Right. And the one that the OP is talking about (the one that's set to 29 in the loop) goes out of scope. So it's not 29 after the loop.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz you and I are thinking the same thing. The tricky bit is that OP is setting `i = 0` but that appears to not work. It's something we can't really debug without more code. (I'm a different Adam than the OP. I should probably stay out of this question :P)

Comment: What is `seq` in `basesMatch(seq[i], seq[j])`?

Comment: @elimad It basically checks to see if two characters match in a certain way or not. I haven't implemented it yet. I don't think it should effect the ```i``` problem though.

Comment: Doing int i = 0 instead of i = 0 works. But that doesn't really solve the mystery.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz Then shouldn't i be uninitialized when it enters the final problem loop? It's retaining its loop value somewhere along the way.

Comment: @Adam No. Once it goes out of scope, it no longer exists. So it has no value and it has no initialization state. To be uninitialized, there would have to be some specific place that wasn't initialized, and there is no place anymore.

Comment: How *precisely* did you determine that `i` wasn't being set?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz I set a breakpoint before the problem loop and walked through the loop. Anyway, my answer fixed the problem. Thanks for having a look.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz You're right about my answer not being correct, actually I forgot that I left the problem line as ```int i = 0```. So changing the for loop bracing didn't do anything, it was just me explicitly re-declaring the variable. The mystery remains.

Answer (score 0):

Check to see if it even enters the loop. num_slices_processed could be null or already < N, so you are never hitting the assignment statement.

Comment: "num_slices_processed could be **null**" ? an `int` being null?

Comment: @elimad an `int` cannot be null.

Comment: @elimad I should have paid closer attention. Now that I have, I join your cause.

Comment: Correct not null, but undefined.